# Scaling based on distance between objects

Tags: geometry-nodes

I was playing with geometry nodes and wanted to scale an object based on its proximity with another and came up with the following but there are two things bothering me:

- I can't figure out where the Viewer Node is supposed to show me the value, there is nothing on the spreadsheet.
- Why is the line red, Distance outputs a float and the radius is a float too

[image]

Comment: Hello ! It's a float **field**, not a float **value**. If you want to get the mean value, use an attribute statistic node.

Comment: Thanks, what is a float field then ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply spoken it is not just one value, but many values. I think the easiest explanation is if you have e.g. a cube and give it a geometry nodes modifier:

[image]

you will see in the spreadsheet...

[image]

that the position is not one value, but 8 values, for each vertex one value.

So although it is just one node, it will be calculated in a loop 8 times for everything which is plugged in after the position node.

And this is how the viewer works:

you plug in the geometry and a "value"/field, and you will see the values in the spreadsheet.

Without viewer the spreadsheet looks like this:

[image]

So if you want to see the distance in the spreadsheet, use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is much clearer now, in my head it was the position of the object itself.
I have managed to do what I wanted initially by replacing the position node by another Object Info for the plane. There is probably a simpler way to get the position of the currently active object but at least it works.

Comment: glad i could clarify it a bit

Comment: This is a very nice and thorourgh explanation. I'll remember to link this in the future since I'm sure there will be a lot of people confused by this distinction. Cheers

Comment: Thank you Gorgious! I appreciate that!